# PDF header signature not found while reading pdf from stream,

Tags: c#, itext, azure-blob-storage

I'm downloading file from blob container & saving in to a stream & trying to read pdf.

```
            //creating a Cloud Storage instance
        CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionstring);
        //Creating a Client to operate on blob
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        // fetching the container based on name
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        //Get a reference to a blob within the container.
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(memStream);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Exception : PDF header signature not found.

Comment: So, are you sure it *is* a pdf file? Have you tried saving it to a local file and inspecting the contents?

Comment: Yes, I tried to save it locally & it works. But not sure why isn't it working with stream.

Comment: Another likely cause can be that after the call to `DownloadToStream`, the stream position is placed *after* the downloaded content, and `PdfReader` expects to be able to read the Pdf from wherever it currently is. Try adding this line of code after `DownloadToStream`: `memStream.Position = 0;`

Comment: works! how can I add this as an answer so it will help others too?

Comment: I will post an answer.

Comment: Please add, I'll upvote it.

Comment: An answer has been posted, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason, as was evident after troubleshooting through the comments was that this line:

```
blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
```

positioned the stream right *after* the downloaded content.

Then, when constructing the pdf reader object it expected to find the Pdf file form the current position.

This is a common problem when dealing with streams that one first write something to and then afterwards tries to read that something, one must remember to reposition the stream if necessary.

In this case, assuming there is only the pdf in the stream, the solution is to reposition the stream back to the start before attempting to read the pdf file:

Add this line:

```
memStream.Position = 0;
```

after the download but before the reader is constructed to reposition.

Here's what the code can look like in this region:

```
blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
memStream.Position = 0; // <----------------------------------- add this line
try
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(memStream);
```